# Selected index changed fail into ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I created a windows forms like this

[image]

As you can see in selected changed event I disable button move to, it works correctly, problem starts when I try to
return an item it to main list, move to button keeps disable instead enable it again when I select item of first list. Someone knows 
what occurs there?

[image]

Events:

```
   private void lstTechUnnotified_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnReturnTo.Enabled = false;
            btnMoveTo.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void lstTechToNotified_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnReturnTo.Enabled = true;
            btnMoveTo.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that there actually is an item being selected since `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event gets fired even when there're no items selected - making the new `SelectedIndex` equal to `-1`. Also, from the way you asking, I expect you want to enable `btnMoveTo` when there's a selected item in `lstTechUnnotified` and otherwise, disable it - and the same for `btnReturnTo` and `lstTechToNotified`; if that's  it, then the easy way is:

```
    private void lstTechUnnotified_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnMoveTo.Enabled = (lstTechUnnotified.SelectedIndex > -1);
    }

    private void lstTechToNotified_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnReturnTo.Enabled = (lstTechToNotified.SelectedIndex > -1);
    }
```

*Though I'm not sure about your button names..*